# How to overcome a map distortion when I am changing the angle in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-plugins

In this project I needed to change the map orientation in 90 degrees. I used a nice plugin "Dockable MirrorMap" that gives the opinion to change each layer separately. [image]
The problem is that the map from the "OpenLayers Plugin" get distorted.[image] This phenomenon also occurred when I changed the angle in the Layer Styling  bar or in the composer. 
Me solution was to save the base map as a raster and then georeferencing it and change the angle. The outcome was good. [image]
However I am wonder: is there is a way to solved this problem in a faster way?

Comment: what is your base layer?

Comment: A "live" map from the OpenLayers plugin. It was the same for OSM, Google etc'

Comment: maybe you should use the supported QuickMapServices plugin

Comment: I tried it and there was no change